# Removed module now Magento displaying Exception: Invalid backend model specified

Tags: magento-1.9, error

After uninstalling the "Background Image Changer" by Licentia the products, products category, and URL rewrites on the back-end display the following error messages:

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

`Error log record number:788538698543`

This error message also displays if I attempt to load any page from the front-end.

I honestly don't know what happen. The project is nearly done and I would die if this error is a fatal one. Please oh please any help!!! I honestly don't know the reason for this error. It kind of happened after uninstalling that extension which didn't work.

and the log in the var folder is:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Invalid backend model specified: scena/catalog_attribute_backend_cimage";i:1;s:6377:"
#0/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
#1/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(205): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
#2/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(998): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->_setAttributeValue(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Array)
#3/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(959): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_loadModelAttributes(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
#4/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), '2', NULL)
#5/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), '2', NULL)
#6/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('2')
#7/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(278): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getCurrentCategory()
#8/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(249): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->_isActiveMenuCategory(Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node))
#9/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(218): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->_addCategoriesToMenu(Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection), Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node), Object(Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu), true)
#10/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer), 'addCatalogToTop...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12/home/rstern123/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#13/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#14/home/rstern123/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(34): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
#15/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/rstern123...')
#16/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#17/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
#23/home/rstern123/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(87): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
#24/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/rstern123...')
#25/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#26/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#30/home/rstern123/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/1column.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#31/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/rstern123...')
#32/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#33/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#36/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#37/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#38/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#39/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45) : Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#40/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#41/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#42/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#43/home/rstern123/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#44/home/rstern123/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#45/home/rstern123/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#46{main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a category attribute that was using a model from the extension you removed. The error is thrown because Magento is trying to load the model and is unable to find it.

A quick way to fix it is to check the **`eav_attribute`** table in the database for this model and remove the attribute that is using it. I'm guessing the attribute itself should not be in use any more since you removed the extension

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed it just fine:) That extension was a problem :/