# Catalog URL Rewrites not working

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, url-rewrite, url-key, source-model

My product pages show 404 page. There is something wrong with the catalog URL rewrites. Screenshot below. The error message I see is Invalid backend model specified: enterprise_catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey

> **Error in system.log:**
>
> ```
> ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php'
> ```
>
> for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/theking1/public_html/si/app/code/local:/home/theking1/public_html/si/app/code/community:/home/theking1/public_html/si/app/code/core:/home/theking1/public_html/si/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php54/lib/php')
>   in /home/theking1/public_html/si/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> **Error in exception.log:**
>
> exception 'Mage_Eav_Exception' with message 'Invalid backend model
>   specified: enterprise_catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey' in
>   /home/theking1/public_html/si/app/Mage.php:580
>
> **Description Image**

[image]

Comment: This post helped resolve the issue. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43462/removed-module-now-magento-displaying-exception-invalid-backend-model-specified

Comment: Could you post the answer here so others can see what it was. Links end up dying and it's much better to put the solution here with the question.